# Making text bold using python pandoc filter

Tags: python, markdown, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

Is there any way to make a bit of text bold using the 'pandocfilters' package (https://github.com/jgm/pandocfilters/tree/master/examples) in pandoc?

As a minimal working example, suppose I have a markdown file ('foo.md'):

```
foobar.
```

I want to write 'filter.py' to be something like

```
from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Str,Emph

def boldify(key, val, fmt, meta):
    if key == 'Str' and "foo" in val:
        # this is the part I can't don't know how to do
        # I would like to make the value be bold
        return [Emph(val)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    toJSONFilter(boldify)
```

So we run the whole thing like

```
pandoc 'foo.md' --filter='filter.py' -o 'foo.docx'
```

Using this, I get the following error:

```
pandoc: Error in $.blocks[0].c[0].c: expected [a], encountered String
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
error, called at pandoc.hs:144:42 in main:Main
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, and I will post what I found (and how I discovered it) in hopes of helping someone else.

### What I found

**The Strong (or bolded) element requires a list of Str elements as its input for this to work**

We should change filter.py to return

```
[Strong([Str(val)])]
```

**instead of**

```
[Strong(val)]
```

or

```
[Strong(Str(val))]
```

### How I found the answer

If we change "foo.md" to:

```
**(foo)** bar
```

And get the abstract syntax tree via:

```
pandoc -t json -s foo.md
```

we get

```
{"blocks":[{"t":"Para","c":[{"t":"Strong","c":[{"t":"Str","c":"(foo)"}]},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"bar"}]}],"pandoc-api-version":[1,17,0,5],"meta":{}}[1]+
```

In particular, the bit:

{"t":"Strong","c":[{"t":"Str","c":"(foo)"}]}

tells us the formatting we need to get a working AST.

Comment: you can also write `-t native` to get the more readable haskell syntax...